# Attempting to convert value into integer

Tags: integer, get-wmiobject

I am very new to Powershell (I have only just poked around in the ISE a little bit for the last couple of days). I'm working on a program to pull battery capacity values from Windows systems and I am stuck in my code.

I want to perform arithmetic (specifically dividing the smaller value by the larger value) on the numerical values that are returned when I call "Remaining Capacity" and "Designed Capacity".

Thank you in advance for your time and energy given to my issue.

-Xeryn

<>

```
 CLS

 $a = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\WMI -Class MSBatteryClass


 $a.RemainingCapacity
 $a.DesignedCapacity

 #Declaring variables
[Int]$r = $a.RemainingCapacity
[Int]$d = $a.DesignedCapacity


#Calling variables
$r
$d


#Calculate capacity percentage
$r / $d
```

When I run $r, ISE outputs:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $r
42340

When I run $d, ISE outputs:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $d
45800

When I run $r / $d, ISE outputs:
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method
named 'op_Division'.
At line:1 char:1

- $r / $d
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Division:String) [], Runti 
  meException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`$a.<param>` is of type `Object[]`, which typically could not be directly converted to type `Int` in PowerShell.
Use `$var.GetType()` to determine the type of a variable.

An easy solution is to begin with casting the variable to `String`, and casting it to `Int` afterwards, like so:

Option A:

```
[Int][String]$r = $a.RemainingCapacity
[Int][String]$d = $a.DesignedCapacity
```

Option B:

```
[Int]$r = $a.RemainingCapacity -as [String]
[Int]$d = $a.DesignedCapacity -as [String]
```

> The -as operator tries to convert the input object to the specified .NET type. If it succeeds, it returns the converted object. If it fails, it returns $null. It does not return an error. See [docs](https://The%20-as%20operator%20tries%20to%20convert%20the%20input%20object%20to%20the%20specified%20.NET%20type.%20If%20it%20succeeds,%20it%20returns%20the%20converted%20object.%20If%20it%20fails,%20it%20returns%20$null.%20It%20does%20not%20return%20an%20error.).

**NOTE:** In order for that to work, the value of `$a.<param>` must be in the correct `Int32` [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-06?view=powershell-7.3#616-conversion-from-string-to-numeric-type).